# NullPointerException in getSVGFromAssets() while using svg in android

Tags: java, android, svg

When I'm trying to get `.svg` file from assets I'm getting `nullPointerException`. Same is happening when I'm calling `getSVGFromResource()` Using https://code.google.com/archive/p/svg-android/downloads library for svg support

```
svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(getAssets(), "aa.svg");
```

I'm getting this exception on above line

**svg file : aa.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 112 90">
<path d="M68,87h-13l20-56h14l20,56h-13l-4-12h-20l-4,12zM75,65h14l-7- 22l-7,22z
" fill="#2a376e"/>
<path d="M15,87h-13l20-56h14l19,56h-12l-4-12h-21l-3,12zM22,65h14l-7-22l-7,22z" fill="#bf2426"/>
<path d="M705,169c5,18,5,27-2,48l-58,172l-62-175c0,0,7-19,11-30c3,0,9,7,9,7c0,0-7-20-4-24l9-24l10,6c-2-6-5-19-5-19l9-28l10,5c0,0-7-19-5-22l24-63c20,47,36,98,54,147zM659,485c1,5,0,11-5,19c1,10,1,13-2,17c-3,3-6,4-10,4c1-3,1-7,0-8c-13-17-42-50-42-50h-15l-14,36l6,10c0,0,13,0,19,0c1,0,2,1,3,3v6c-1-1-3-2-4-3c-14,0-24,0-37,1l-4,2c-2-5,2-9,5-9c3,0,6,0,5-2c-1-3-2-4-5-7h-16c-16-46-33-92-47-139c6,0,14-3,14-3c0,0-16-6-20-15c-3-9-14-40-14-40c0,0,9-1,13-3c-5-4-18-8-20-14c-7-18-11-35-11-35c0,0,16-1,14-2c-9-4-21-16-21-16c0,0-11-31-11-31c1-1,16,0,16,0c-4-8-16-12-13-23c4-13,9-26,12-34l9,5c-1-5-4-23-4-23l12-35l9,7l-3-24l20-51l52,147l109,310zM475,476l-5-8l-6,8h-22l48-74l27,74h-14l-5-8l-5,8h-18z"    fill="#2a376e" transform="scale(0.1)"/>
</svg>
```

**LogCat**

```
 com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParseException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float java.lang.Float.floatValue()' on a null object reference
            at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.parse(Unknown Source)
            at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(Unknown Source)
            at com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVGParser.getSVGFromAsset(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me out why this is happing .. Thanks !!

Comment: Closing this as a general NPE question seems harsh.  This is happening inside a library.  Asking a question here seems reasonable - before having to attempt to debug a library.  I've reopened it.

Comment: This library will not work for some svg file when I changed the svg file no exception came..

Answer (score 0):

There is obviously something in that SVG file that svg-android isn't coping well with when parsing.  It's a very simple file, so there aren't many candidates.

You could try removing `<path>` elements one at a time to see which, if any, are causing the exception.

It's possible it is the dense, no-spaces, formatting of the path commands that is the problem.  Try adding spaces to the path command strings. Eg.:

```
d="M 15,87 h -13 l 20 -56 h 14 l 19,56 h -12 l -4 -12 h -21 l -3,1 ..etc..
```

Or it could be the newline that is in the first path command attribute. Try fixing that.

Otherwise, there are several different forks of the svg-android library which have had various bug fixes applied.  You might try one of them.

`<plug>`Or you could try my library, AndroidSVG`</plug>`

Comment: Thanks !! please provide link for your library :)